# React transition group animate between components (fade in component in place of another)

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

I'm using `react-transition-group` for animations in my app.

I have a Popup where I want to animate between two contents. I want to make the first content fade out and the second content appear in its place.

So far I have a problem where while animating the second content appears below the first one while the first one is still visible. (See the screenshot)

Any help will be much appreciated.

[image]

My code

```
const [stage, setStage] = useState('register');

  function changeStage(stageVal) {
    setStage(stageVal);
  }
...
<Popup togglePopupWindow={togglePopupWindow} setStage={setStage}>
        <CSSTransitionGroup
          transitionName="example"
          transitionEnterTimeout={500}
          transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
        >
          {stage === 'register' && (
          <>
            <Form>
              <h2>Register</h2>
              <Input type="text" placeholder="Login" />
              <Input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
              <Input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
              <Button text="Register" />
            </Form>
            <p>
              <span>Already registered?</span>
              <Button className="popup__login" text="Login" onClick={() => changeStage('login')} />
            </p>
        </>
          )
      }
          {stage === 'login' && (
          <Form>
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <Input type="text" placeholder="Login" />
            <Input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <Button text="Register" />
          </Form>
          )
   }
        </CSSTransitionGroup>
      </Popup>
```

Styles

```
.example-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    }

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.example-leave {
   opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out `.example-enter` and `.example-leave` on each of the `...-active` CSS properties.. You set `.example-enter` to 0 opacity and then replace the `.example-enter` to `1`.. meaning you're setting `1` on `.example-enter` with your `.example-enter-active` after the initial declaration... so the 0 is overwritten.

```
.example-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    }
.example-enter-active {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.example-leave {
   opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave-active {
   opacity: 0;
   transition: 
}
```

Comment: Looking at the DOM what is happening is that the second form appears below the first one before the fist one disappears